# Update rows at ListView

Tags: android, sqlite

please help me to find solutions.I have 2 Activity A and B.Data come from B through `OnActivityResult` method,saving in `DataBase` and shown in the `ListView`.

I need to update data with `OnItemClick` method.But problem is how to do that.I know one way,to create a new Activity with `EditText`, but I think its not correct.

What else can I use?

I have this method in DB:

```
public boolean updateRow(long rowId, String task, String date,String grup){
        String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
        ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        newValues.put(KEY_TASK, task);
        newValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);
        newValues.put(KEY_GRUPS, grup);
        // Insert it into the database.
        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) != 0;
}
```

Comment: can you be more descriptive and add code to show what have you done till now?

Comment: just add your data in your custom list and use notifydatasetchanged